# Laravel 8 - friendly url that call multiple controllers depending on match (products, categories, pages) - How to design it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

i would like to build a route that catch clean seo friendly url and call correct controller to display page. Examples:

```
https://mypage.com/some-friendly-url-separated-with-dashes [PageController]
https://mypage.com/some-cool-eletronic-ipod [ProductController]
https://mypage.com/some-furniture-drawers [CategoryController]
```

So I have in app route:

```
Route::get('/{friendlyUrl}', 'RouteController@index');
```

Each friendly url is a unique url(string) so there is no duplicate between pages/products/categories. There is also no pattern between urls - they could be any string used in seo(only text plus dashes/ sometimes params).

Is it wise to build one db table that keeps all urls in on place with info what to call ( url | controller_name | action_name) - as an example.

Another question is - how to call different controllers depending on url used? (for above example -> RouteController catch friendly urls -finds match in db table -> then calls correct controller)

Many thanks for any help.
Have a nice day

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two approaches you can take to this.

Proactive:

In `web.php`

```
$slugs = Product::pluck('slug');
foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
    Route::get($slug, 'ProductController@index');
}

$slugs = Category::pluck('slug');
foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
    Route::get($slug, 'CategoryController@index');
}

$slugs = Page::pluck('slug');
foreach ($slugs as $slug) {
    Route::get($slug, 'PagesController@index');
}
```

Then you can determine the product in the appropriate controler via e.g.

```
$actualItem = Product::where('slug', request()->path())->first();
```

The downside to this approach is that all routes are registered on every request even if they are not used meaning you hit the database on every request to populate them. Also, routes can't be cached when using this approach.

Reactive:

In this approach you use the fallback route:

In `web.php`:

```
Route::fallback(function (Request $request) {
   if (Page::where('slug', $request->path())->exists()) {
        return app()->call([ PageController::class, 'index' ]);
   }
   if (Category::where('slug', $request->path())->exists()) {
        return app()->call([ CategoryController::class, 'index' ]);
   }
   if (Product::where('slug', $request->path())->exists()) {
        return app()->call([ ProductController::class, 'index' ]);
   }
   abort(404);
});
```

Comment: One more question - if I use app()->call() is it possible to get /pass additional params from url? (example ?page=2)  Additionally i could create one db table -> add all slugs there and use fallback to query this table and return correct controller. This will solve my problem and a will avoid 3 queries (so one query in total).

Comment: The parameters in `request()` should be retained so you could use `request()` as normal. Also if you want to create an extra "routing" table my main concern with that would be that it's hard to specify the foreign constraints from multiple tables so you might end up with inconsistencies like someone renamed a slug but the routing table didn't get updated, if you are not careful. This can probably be solved using triggers or eloquent events though.

Comment: After rethinking i will go with route table with fallback route to check and call controllers. If i remember correctly if i use function in route there will be problem with route caching (use of closure error)

Answer (score 1):

You need create a table call slugs.
Then create a unique slug (can be auto generated or specified) for each page, product, category.
slug records also have columns to get Controller and params, ex: `type` and `id`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you just use a prefix for each type like this:

```
https://mypage.com/pages/some-friendly-url-separated-with-dashes [PageController]
https://mypage.com/products/some-cool-eletronic-ipod [ProductController]
https://mypage.com/category/some-furniture-drawers [CategoryController]
```

Then for achieving this, create three routes like this

```
Route::get('pages/{friendlyUrl}', 'PageController@index');
Route::get('products/{friendlyUrl}', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('category/{friendlyUrl}', 'CategoryController@index');
```

These URLs would be SEO friendly

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well prefix is easy - main idea is to have short and clean urls with no prefix at all.